How import flask SQLAlchemy db to blueprints?
I have a Flaks application with modules. What approach should I use to create instances of SQLAlchemy in the blueprints? My init.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .config import PGHOST, PGUSER, PGPORT, PGDATABASE, PGPASSWORD
from .auth import auth_bp
from .user_ui import user_ui_bp



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"postgresql://{PGUSER}:{PGPASSWORD}@{PGHOST}:{PGPORT}/{PGDATABASE}"
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret_key"
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    

    # Register Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(user_ui_bp)

    return app


my auth.py blueprint
import datetime
import jwt
import bcrypt
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify
from .db_utils import DbUser
from .config import SECRET_KEY

auth_bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth_bp.route('/api/register', methods=["POST"])
def register():
    data = request.get_json()
    password = data['password'].encode('utf-8')

    # Hash the password
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

    user = DbUser(username=data['username'], password=hashed_password.decode('utf-8'))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'message': 'User registered successfully'}), 201


I need initiate db, but I have no idea where I should import it from. 
I am not even sure what approach I should be using.

I tried initiating new instance of SQLAlchemy in my blueprint
db = SQLAlchemy()
But then it ended up with "RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead."
I also tried importing db from app, but "ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)"
Also tried
db = current_app.config['db']
But get error
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.

I feel like getting context from current app makes the most sense but I am not sure how to approach this...

You should try initialize db outside of the method create_app:
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .config import PGHOST, PGUSER, PGPORT, PGDATABASE, PGPASSWORD
from .auth import auth_bp
from .user_ui import user_ui_bp



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"postgresql://{PGUSER}:{PGPASSWORD}@{PGHOST}:{PGPORT}/{PGDATABASE}"
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret_key"        

    # Register Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(user_ui_bp)

    return app


app = create_app()

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)

You can also double check with the docs https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/.
